# How to assign objects from two different classes?

Tags: c#, class, reference, console-application

I have two constructors Employee `Employee(string id, string FirstName, string LastName)` and Project`Project(string PID, string PName)` . To add an employee or view the whole project list, I have created a business logic :

```
   public class Employeeclass
    {
        public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; } = new List<Employee>();

        public void AddEmployee(Employee employee)
        {
            Employees.Add(employee);
        }

        public List<Employee> GetAllEmployee()
        {
            return Employees;
        }
}     
public class Projectclass
    {
        public List<Project> Projects { get; set; } = new List<Project>();

        public void AddProject(Project project)
        {
            Projects.Add(project);
        }

        public List<Project> GetAllProject()
        {
            return Projects;
        }
    }
```

In this business logic, I want to assign a project to an employee. For this I generated a separate constructor `Assign(string EmpId, string PID)`and created a class to assign the projects. First I add a employee and then a project. By using EmpId and PID, I want to assign the projects to employee. It was possible to do so when all the business logic was under a single class.

```
public class Assignclass
    {
        public List<Assign> Assigns { get; set; } = new List<Assign>();
        //assign employees to project
        public void Add(Assign assign)
        {
            var id = assign.EmpId;
            var pid = assign.PID;
            var emp = Employees.Find(a => a.EmpId == id);
            var prjct = Projects.Find(c => c.PID == pid);
            if (emp != null || prjct != null)
            {
                Assigns.Add(assign);
            }
        }
}
```

I could use this code when I have put Employeeclass, Projectclass and Assignclass as a single class. Now that I have segregated the classes in Employeeclass, Projectclass, Assignclass; I can't use the same code as `Employees` and `Projects` can't exist without context so I created reference variables for Employees and Projects.

```
public void Add(Assign assign)
        {
            Employeeclass classA = new Employeeclass();
            Projectclass classB = new Projectclass();
            
            List<Employee> Employes = classA.Employees;
            List<Project> Projcts = classB.Projects;
            //List<Assign> Assignss = classC.Assigns;
            var id = assign.EmpId;
            var pid = assign.PID;
            var emp = Employes.Find(a => a.EmpId == id);
            var prjct = Projcts.Find(c => c.PID == pid);
            if (emp != null || prjct != null)
            {
                Assigns.Add(assign);
            }
        }
```

But it shows while debugging that there are no elements in Employes.  I can't use Find to find an employee with the same EmpId; same with Projects and Projcts. How should I assign the project to employees and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `public List<Employee> **Employees**` isn't real code. Please post real code with enough detail for us to actually run your code and see the issue you're facing. We need a [mcve].

Comment: @Enigmativity I have made an edit and now it is code, do I need to add a console application?

Comment: You need to add enough code for us to copy, paste, and run your code. You've still got the word `class` at the end of your class names, but not inside the code. It's still not real.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I have added the complete working code.

Comment: Except for `Assignlogic`. You need to, please, check that it's complete.

Comment: You also have two `break;` on `case "6"`. Please make sure you have real code.

Comment: Please start a new project, from scratch, and add code until it is a [mcve]. Then give us that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your public void Add(Assign assign) function you make classA and classB, these are new objects of this class and have no values in them.
If you want to use the function like this you could make the function like this:
public void Add(Assign assing, Employeeclass classA, Projectclass classB) ...
And then you can give your existing object with there value with them.

Comment: If I do that, what parameter will I need to use in place of classA or classB  while calling the function in console-application?

Comment: The objects you make for the EmployeeClass and ProjectClass, the same objects where you added the employees and projects you want to link.

Answer (score 0):

This design looks like a database design.
In C# it is easy to have relations, for example by a class simply having a property with type of another class.

I would just give a quick hint for a different design (instead of having an entity for the relation itself):

```
class Project
{
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; } = new List<Employee>();
    // (...) other properties
}
```

So when you want to assign an `Employee` to a project, you can simply do

```
Employee e = GetEmployee(...);
project.Employees.Add(e);
```

Does that help?

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't help.